# How do I add an inner class for the two buttons named Admin Login and Teacher Login in Java?

Tags: inner-classes

I want to show Admin Login form when the Admin Login button is clicked and the Teacher Login when the Teacher button is clicked.
[The three forms: Main form with two buttons, Admin Login and Teacher Login; Admin Login form and Teacher Login form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1plN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

U can implement this by changing css property display =none; and display=block on clicking a button as simple as that..

Comment: thanks. I would like to do it in a desktop program not in a web program...